# Quantile regression with censored data. Quantiles not fitted

Tags: r, censoring, quantile-regression

I'm trying to fit a quantile regression model for rigth censoring data and I'm using R with the package quantreg and its function  crq. I'm trying the Portnoy method that it's suposed to estimate the full range of tau (quantiles) , but the results only contains 85 taus, ending in tau=0.4 and giving me estimated values of that lasts taus that are very far away from the real 0.4 quantile and more around 0.95 quantile.

I read in the quantreg doc that Portnoy and Peng-Huang may be unable to estimate upper conditional quantiles if censoring is heavy in the upper in the upper tail, but this doesn't seem to be my case. In fact the general distribution summary of time is:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.0   223.0   447.0   482.5   714.0  1251.0
```

the quantiles vary obviously with levels of VAR1 and VAR2 but the shape of the distribution is almost the same.I can produce Kaplan-Mier estimation without problem.

Here is my syntax

```
qreg1<-crq(Surv(TIME,EVENT,type="right")~VAR1+VAR2,
       data=DATA_TRAIN,method = "Portnoy")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that the syntax has changed. Now one has to call `summary()` to get the estimate and confidence intervals.